# "dotnet pack" command against .NET Standard PCL says Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package

I want to create a NuGet package from my .NET Standard 1.2 PCL. All I get is this message when I execute `dotnet pack` under my project folder.

> Sequence contains no elements

Does somebody know what's happening?

Maybe it's because dotnet pack is only intended for .NET Core projects?